# How to benefit from cpu cache in a entity component system game engine?

Tags: c++, architecture, entity-system, memory-efficiency, entity-component

I often read in the ECS game engine documentations that is a good architecture for using cpu cache wisely.

But I can't figure how we can benefit from cpu cache.

If components are saved in an array (or a pool), in contiguous memory, it's a good way to use cpu cache BUT only if we read the components sequentially.

When we use systems, they need entities list which are list of entities that have components with specific types.

But these lists give the components in a random way, not sequentially.

So how to design a ECS to maximize the cache hit ?

**EDIT :**

By example, a Physic system needs an entities list for entity that has the RigidBody and Transform components (There is a pool for RigidBody and a pool for Transform components).

So its loop for updating entities will be like this :

```
for (Entity eid in entitiesList) {
    // Get rigid body component
    RigidBody *rigidBody = entityManager.getComponentFromEntity<RigidBody>(eid);

    // Get transform component
    Transform *transform = entityManager.getComponentFromEntity<Transform>(eid);

    // Do something with rigid body and transform component
}
```

The problem is that the RigidBody component of entity1 can be at the index 2 of its pool and the Tranform component of entity1 at the index 0 of its pool (because some entities can have some components and not the other and because of adding / deleting entities / components randomly).

So even if components are contiguous in memory, they are read randomly and so it will have more cache miss, no ?

Unless there is a way to prefetch the next components in the loop ?

Comment: can you show us how are you allocating each component?

Comment: With a simple pool allocator and a Handle manager for having component reference to manage relocation of components in the pool (to keep the components contiguous in memory).

Comment: Your example loop presumes that component updates are interleaved per-entity. In many cases it's possible to update components in bulk by component type (eg. update all rigidbody components first, then update all transforms with the finished rigidbody data, then update all rendering data with the new transforms...) - this can improve cache use for each component update. I think this type of structure is what Nick Wiggill is suggesting below.

Comment: It's my example which is bad, in fact, it's more the "update all transforms with the finished rigid body data" system than the Physic system. But the problem stays the same, in these systems (update transform with rigid body, update rendering with transform, ...), we will need to have more than one type of component at the same time.

Comment: Not sure if this may be relevant too? http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/6345/sponsored_feature_dataoriented_.php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Mick West's article](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/) explains the process of linearising entity component data, in full. It worked for the Tony Hawk series, years ago, on much less impressive hardware than we have today, to greatly improve performance. He basically used global, pre-allocated arrays for each distinct type of entity data (position, score and whatnot) and references each array in a distinct phase of his system-wide `update()` function. You can assume that the data for each entity would be at the same array index in each of these global arrays, so for instance, if the player is created first, it might have its data at `[0]` in each array.

Even more specific to cache optimisation, [Christer Ericsson's slides](http://www.research.scea.com/research/pdfs/GDC2003_Memory_Optimization_18Mar03.pdf) for C and C++.

To give a bit more detail, you should try to use contiguous memory blocks (most easily allocated as arrays) per each type of data (e.g. position, x y and z), to ensure good locality of reference, utilising each such data block in distinct `update()` phases for the sake of temporal locality i.e. to ensure the cache isn't flushed via the hardware's LRU algorithm before you've reused any data you intend to reuse, within a given `update()` call. As you've implied, what you don't want to do is to allocate your entities and components as discrete objects via `new`, as data of different types on each entity instance will then be interleaved, reducing locality of reference.

If you have interdependencies between components (data) such that you absolutely cannot afford to have some data separated from it's associated data (eg. Transform + Physics, Transform + Renderer) then you may opt to replicate Transform data in both the Physics and Renderer arrays, assuring that all pertinent data fits the cache line width for each performance-critical operation.

Remember also that L2 and L3 cache (if you can assume these for your target platform) do a lot to alleviate the problems that L1 cache may suffer, such as a restrictive line width. So even on an L1 miss, these are safety nets that will most often prevent callouts to main memory, which is orders of magnitude slower than callouts to any level of cache.

**Note on writing data** Writing does not call out to main memory. By default, today's systems have *write-back caching* enabled: writing a value only writes it to cache (initially), not to main memory, so you will not be bottlenecked by this. It is only when data is requested from main memory (won't happen while it's in cache) and is stale, that main memory will be updated from cache.

Comment: Just a note for anyone who might be new to C++: `std::vector` is basically a dynamically-resizeable array and hence is also contiguous (de facto in older C++ versions and de jure in newer C++ versions).  Some implementations of `std::deque` are also "contiguous enough" (though not Microsoft's).

Comment: Thank you but I already read these articles, ECS puts the components of same type in an array (or a pool for avoiding new / delete overhead). The problem is when we read these components, we can't read them sequentially because of the entities lists of the systems. I updated my question with an example.

Comment: @Johnmph Quite simply: If you don't have locality of reference, you don't have anything. If two pieces of data are closely related (such as spatial and physics information), i.e. they are processed together, then you may well have to compact them as a single component, interleaved. But bear in mind then that any other logic (say, AI) that leverages that spatial data may then suffer as a result of the spatial data not being included alongside *it*. So it depends on what requires the most performance (perhaps physics in your case). Does that make sense?

Comment: @Johnmph yes, I totally agree with Nick it's about how they are stored in memory, if you have entity with pointers to two components that are far away in memory you don't have locality, they have to fit in a cache line.

Comment: @NickWiggill Yes, but if we need to compact the related component types together, we will need to add also the Render component and some other components that use Transform / RigidBody / Render (or choosing to compact only some to have the most performance like you said) and the architecture will become a OOP system, and it's why I don't understand how the ECS can be cache friendly like the documentations says. Thank you for clarifications.

Comment: @Johnmph: Indeed, Mick West's article assumes minimal interdependencies. So: Minimise dependencies; Replicate data along cache lines where you cannot minimise those dependencies... e.g. include Transform alongside *both* RigidBody *and* Render; and in order to fit cache lines, you may need to reduce your data atoms as much as possible... this could be achieved in part by going from floating point to fixed point (4 bytes vs 2 bytes) per decimal point value. But one way or another, no matter how you do it, your data has to fit the cache line width as concept3d noted, for maximal performance.

Comment: @Johnmph another thing you need to keep in mind, is that as far as your game is performing well, just don't get too caught with cache optimization. Don't get me wrong it's still a must for huge games. But not really for smaller ones. I advise you to profile first then optimize.

Comment: @NickWiggill I can't see how replicate data could help, we move the cache problem from the components reading to the components replicating (because we still need to read the Physic and Render components together to replicate their transform data), no ?

Comment: @concept3d yes you are right but it's the base of my game engine, if I don't design this well, it will be difficult to modify it after.

Comment: @Johnmph. No. Whenever you write Transform data, you simply write it to both arrays. It's not those writes you need to be worried about. Once you send off a write, it's as good as done. It's the *reads*, later on in the update, when you run Physics and Renderer, that *must* have access to all pertinent data, immediately, in a single cache line right up close and personal to the CPU. Also, if you really need it all together, then you either do further replications or you make sure physics, transform and render fit a single cache line... 64 bytes is common and is actually quite a lot of data!...

Comment: There is more to this: You may not even need replication, but that depends very much on the size of your data set: If all critical data fits in a few megs, it may fit your L2 or L3 cache which is "good enough" (orders of magnitude better than a callout to memory and acceptable for even the most intensive algorithms). Perhaps some mobiles, though, only have one level of cache. I'm not sure what you've spec'ed your engine for.

Comment: @NickWiggill Ah yes, write operation can be delayed!!! I will do some tests with that replicate technic. For the L2 / L3 cache, i write for smartphone, there has a L2 cache but no L3 in this CPU. Thanks a lot!